# How to access public download folder in every platform in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I need to create a backup service so I intend to save the SQLite database file on each platform. The saved file should be available *after the uninstall of the app*.

I intend to use the ***Downloads*** folder (which should be available on every platform).

I have created an interface and use the following code per platform:

**Interface**:

```
public interface IBackupService
{
  string GetDownloadPath();
}
```

**Android**:

```
public string GetDownloadPath()
{
  return Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads;
}
```

**UWP**:

```
public string GetDownloadPath()
{
  return Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.???????;
}
```

What should I do about that? Is there a public library that I could use?

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be a general downloads folder as per this documentation on [KnownFolders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227151). So your assumption on the Downloads folder being on every platform doesn't seem to be correct.

If we dive in a bit further we get to the [DocumentsLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.storage.knownfolders.documentslibrary) which seems the obvious choice for this kind of purpose, but it is not. Microsoft says:

> The Documents library is not intended for general use. For more info,
>   see [App capability declarations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt270968). Also, see the following blog post.
>   [Dealing with Documents: How (not) to use the documentsLibrary capability in Windows Store apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/05/09/dealing-with-documents-how-not-to-use-the-documentslibrary-capability-in-windows-store-apps.aspx)

The paragraph after that seems to describe what we have to do then;

> If your app has to create and update files that only your app uses,
>   consider using the app's local folder. Get the app's local folder from
>   the [Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder) property.

So, as I can extract from your question you only want to use storage for your app, so the `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` seems to be the right choice according to Microsoft.

Comment: I might be misunderstood: I need to have the file _after the app is uninstalled_. So using LocalFolder is not a good solution for me.

Comment: Note that leaving files behind when an app is uninstalled is bad practice, but if that really is your requirement then this is not the solution indeed. You could then choose to use the `DocumentsLibrary` after all as it equivalent to the 'My documents' folder on a regular PC. But please note the limitations Microsoft has put on it.